# Spring MVC: Send form data as JSON or XML

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC. Challenge is that I want to send all the form data in JSON or XML format to the Cotroller method.
Does Spring MVC provides it out of the box? If not then how would I receive all the form data in Controller method? After receiving all the form data  it, I can transform it to JSON or XML.
With my limited experience I can get individual value with the help of `@RequestPrameter` but not sure how would I receive complete data in controller method?

> Note: I don't want to model form values to any model object. Just want to receive values in
>   JSON/XML format and save it to the database as a clob.

Comment: Himanshu, did you find a way to send xml data from the form and receive it in your controller? If yes, can you post it here.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can get complete form data to your Controller.

1. You can get using request.getParameter("element_name");

Using this approach you are not using the Spring MVC's Form Element-Class Property Binding Feature.

1. You can create POJO class of the element present inside your HTML Form.

In this approach you no need to get each value of form using request.getParameter("element_name"); instead you will get filled POJO object, which can be more handy to work on.

Also, you can handle data type binding errors more easily and in neat way.

For form element to class property binding refer, 
Best Help : http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-form-handling-example/

---

For your requirement, you can't directly get in JSON/XML Format, Instead you need to call javascript function onSubmit and then create JSON/XML of form you needed and then you can submit the form.

Comment: I have mentioned it in my Note that I can not create a POJO/model class for the form.

Comment: You edited and mentioned that Later, prior to it only I posted above answer.

Comment: That's ok. I think there is someway getting the JSON form data by using Jackson/JAXB as view resolver.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion best way to implement this is sending the data in json format via http POST request, and get it in controller method:

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/data", headers = "Accept=application/json") 
   @ResponseBody
    public List postData(@RequestBody String data) { {
        ...
        // here for example you can use GSON or Jackson to deserialize json to java instance
    }
```

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong `@ResponseBody` takes care of the response from controller method. Here I am facing issue with the RequestBody.

Comment: Ok sorry, I misunderstood your problem. I would edit my answer.

Comment: Would `@RequestBody String data` give all the form data as JSON

Comment: As String, but you sended it in JSON format, so that's not a problem.